# Absolutely nothing will allow me to login to mysql root?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Followed numerous forums, threads, tutorials, SO questions and nothing will allow me to login to root.

I changed "AllowNoPassword"=TRUE in both locations in the config. Nothing.

Followed http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html, successfully changed the passwords, and it STILL won't let me login.

The last thing I did was:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
* mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
* mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

mysql

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
* Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
* Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
* Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

CTRL+C

kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`

/etc/init.d/mysql start
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld
* Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly.
```

(Output is *)

And nothing. Still get access denied when trying `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` and then entering the password. I'm not a pro and this is actually a learning server that I setup multiple instances of some sites and now none of the passwords are working.

In the above steps, I know for a fact I updated the passwords because I even tried changing the sites individual db passwords and now they're broken because the CMS can't connect to the db anymore with a different password.

EDIT: looking back it appears there are now 4 different root users? Should I delete 3? If yes, do I know which ones to delete?

Comment: *I might be wrong*, but you have `mysql.user` and later on you site the username as `-u root`... I think "user" would have to be replaced with "root".  Double emphasis, **I might be wrong**.

Comment: Great. Another tutorial that just assumes everyone knows everything. Thanks a lot. And no thanks to the official mysql tutorials. I figured mysql.user pertained to the table.

Comment: Um, what?  Did that help?

Comment: OK.  Looked at the documentation and based on your code above, it appears you missed steps 4 & 5 which include the command `mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &` (and, yes, my previous "I might be wrong" comment was wrong.)

Comment: Did you check the `host` field for the record(s) whose password you changed? Can you provide the actual commands/output you see, instead of trying to recreate them with typos (*PR **V** IVILEGES*) and `blah blah`s?

Comment: @JeremyMiller I tried that step in the previous attempt, the only part of that tutorial that actually seemed to do anything was the generic instructions, which has the --skip-grant-tables options under the unix instructions.

Comment: @DCoder I will update my question with the actual outputs.

Comment: If you see 4 root users, why did your `UPDATE` only affect one of them? What are the hostnames associated with those users (`SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user`)?

Comment: Idk why it affected only 1 row. I checked the output again and it was copied correctly. The hosts listed are: root 127.0.0.1; root ::1; site-test.com localhost; debian-sys-maint localhost; sitetest.com localhost; phpmyadmin localhost; root localhost; root test-apache;